# Saving output in the same folder as the original script in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I run `Run.py` where I am calling `File1.py` which is located in another folder `1`. How do I save the output of `File1.py` in `1.txt` in the same folder in which it is located and not the folder in which `Run.py` is located?

`Run.py` is

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.run(['python',rf'C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept15_2022\\Test\\1\\File1.py']))
```

`File.py` is

```
import csv

A=1
B=2
C=A+B
print(C)

with open('1.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    print(C)
    f.writelines('R'+ '\n')
    f.write(str(C))
```

Comment: Why even this construct? This seems unneccessary. To answer your question: You can pass your current path as argument to `File1.py` and read it with `sys.argv[1]` (index `0` is the script's name, `1` the first argument and so on).

Comment: @white I think you misunderstood the question, it's the other way round. He wants to store the text as a sibling to File.py, not to Run.py

Comment: @JeanotZubler That's right. I want to store ```1.txt``` in the same folder as ```File.py```.

Comment: That makes it even easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the path of the currently running script with the `__file__` variable. So something like this would probably work:

```py
import os

current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "1.txt")

with open(filename, "w") as f:
  # rest of code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the path where the file.py is located to that 1.txt. You can get the path where file.py is located by:

```
import os
file_py_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Explore os.path.join() to join paths, this way you will avoid problems related to diff filesystems.